# Keyboard events onKeyPress on react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, react-hooks, keylistener

```js
const CarForm = () => {
    const data = useContext(userContext)
    const [showForm, setShowForm] = useState(false);

    const update = () => {
        db.collection("prospects").doc(data.document).update({
            plates: carData.plates,
            motorNumber: carData.motorNumber,
            serialNumber: carData.serialNumber
        })
        .then(function() {
            console.log(`Document successfully updated!`);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            // The document probably doesn't exist.
            console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
        });
    }

    const [plates, setPlates] = useState();
    const [enteredPlates, setEnteredPlates] = useState();
    const [found, setFound] = useState();
    const [carData, setCarData] = useState();

    const getPlates = () => {
        let plates = db.collection('plates');
        plates.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
            const docs = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                docs.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})
            });
            setPlates(docs);
        });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getPlates();
    }, [])

    const findPlates = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(plates.find(p => p.plates === enteredPlates)) {
            const x = plates.find(p => p.plates === enteredPlates)
            setCarData({...carData, plates: x.plates, motorNumber: x.motorNumber, serialNumber: x.serialNumber})
            setFound(true)
        } else {
            setCarData({...carData, plates: enteredPlates})
            setFound(false);
        }
        setShowForm(true)
    }
    const handleEvent = (event) => {
        if(event.keyCode === 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            setEnteredPlates(event.target.value);
            findPlates()
        }
    }

    return ( 
        <>
        {
            plates ? 
            <div className='Container'>
            <form className='data-form'>
                <label htmlFor='placa'>Número de placa</label>
                <div style={style.cont}>
                    <input type='text' name='placa' id='placas' onKeyPress={handleEvent}/>
                    <i className="fa fa-search" onClick={findPlates} style={style.icon}></i>
                </div>
                {showForm === true &&
                  <>
                  {
                    found === true ? 
                    <>
                        <label htmlFor='serie'>Número de serie</label>
                        <input type='text' name='serie' value={carData.serialNumber}/>
                        <label htmlFor='motor'>Número de motor</label>
                        <input type='text' name='motor' value={carData.motorNumber}/>
                    </>
                    :
                    <>
                        <label htmlFor='serie'>Número de serie</label>
                        <input type='text' name='serie' onChange={e=> setCarData({...carData, serialNumber: e.target.value})}/>
                        <label htmlFor='motor'>Número de motor</label>
                        <input type='text' name='motor' onChange={e=> setCarData({...carData, motorNumber: e.target.value})}/>
                    </>
                }
                  </>
                }
            </form>
            {showForm === true &&
              <GeneralButton text='Continuar' route='/datos-personales' back='/planes' click={update}/>
            }
        </div>
        : <Loading />
    }
        </>
     );
}
 
export default CarForm;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I have a problem with my code. I'm trying to fire a function when the user press enter in an 'input' type=text, that set the input value in a state and then execute a function that search the entered value in an object. Until now my code doesn't work, i don't get what i'm doing wrong, could somebody help me please? thanks a lot for your help

this is my function

```
const handleEvent = (event) => {
        if(event.keyCode === 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            setEnteredPlates(event.target.value);
            findPlates()
        }
    }
```

and this is the input

```
<input type='text' name='placa' id='placas' onKeyPress={handleEvent}/>
```

this is the other function that is called from the handler:

```
    const findPlates = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(plates.find(p => p.plates === enteredPlates)) {
            const x = plates.find(p => p.plates === enteredPlates)
            setCarData({...carData, plates: x.plates, motorNumber: x.motorNumber, serialNumber: x.serialNumber})
            setFound(true)
        } else {
            setCarData({...carData, plates: enteredPlates})
            setFound(false);
        }
        setShowForm(true)
    }
```

and this is all the return part:

```
return ( 
        <>
        {
            plates ? 
            <div className='Container'>
            <form className='data-form'>
                <label htmlFor='placa'>Número de placa</label>
                <div style={style.cont}>
                    <input type='text' name='placa' id='placas' onKeyPress={handleEvent}/>
                    <i className="fa fa-search" onClick={findPlates} style={style.icon}></i>
                </div>
                {showForm === true &&
                  <>
                  {
                    found === true ? 
                    <>
                        <label htmlFor='serie'>Número de serie</label>
                        <input type='text' name='serie' value={carData.serialNumber}/>
                        <label htmlFor='motor'>Número de motor</label>
                        <input type='text' name='motor' value={carData.motorNumber}/>
                    </>
                    :
                    <>
                        <label htmlFor='serie'>Número de serie</label>
                        <input type='text' name='serie' onChange={e=> setCarData({...carData, serialNumber: e.target.value})}/>
                        <label htmlFor='motor'>Número de motor</label>
                        <input type='text' name='motor' onChange={e=> setCarData({...carData, motorNumber: e.target.value})}/>
                    </>
                }
                  </>
                }
            </form>
            {showForm === true &&
              <GeneralButton text='Continuar' route='/datos-personales' back='/planes' click={update}/>
            }
        </div>
        : <Loading />
    }
        </>
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const handleEvent = (event) => {
    if(event.key === 'Enter') {
        event.preventDefault();
        setEnteredPlates(event.target.value);
        findPlates()
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your help, I tried it too and it stills not working

Comment: Can you paste your code here? I've just tried it and it works fine

Comment: I already added the code inside the question. thanks

Comment: Please paste full code needed to reproduce your problem in your question, use snippet or code block